# Silent push notification and normal push notification using OneSignal

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal, silentpush

Is it possible to implement silent push notifications and normal push notifications together in one Android application using OneSignal?

I have checked with silent notifications and normal notifications separately, but can't implement it together.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to implement the `NotificationExtenderService` and decide based on the notification type you set up what you want to do with the incoming notification. If you want to handle it return false in the receiver, otherwise true

More detail
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-customizations#section-background-data-and-notification-overriding

Comment: I have implemented NotificationExtenderService  and return true for silent notification but for normal notification overrideSettings to display notification.How can i do both in the same class extends NotificationExtenderService

Comment: You need to be able to decided on your own (you need to come up with that based on the notification you received) if the notification is silent or not. That is up to you to implement and "mark" a notification silent. After that you can return true or false dynamically after deciding if the notification is silent or needs to be displayed to the user.

Comment: how do i do this in iOS?

Comment: @UserID0908 By going to the one signal's iOS doc and reading about Background Notifications

Answer (score 3):

It seems I am late in the party but it may help someone who is in need. You don't have to extend `NotificationExtenderService` for silent notification. Just include parameter `"content_available": true` to send silent notifications but remember, do not include `heading`, `contents` parameters else `content_available` will be ignored.

```dart
{
    "app_id": "<<your OneSignal app id>>",
    "include_external_user_ids": ["<<user id>>"], 
    "content_available": true,
    "data": {"foo": "bar"}
}
```

Comment: does this solution still working as on today Feb 2022?

Comment: I haven't tried it recently but it still works using their REST API [https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/data-notifications#backgrounddata-notifications-with-the-rest-api]

Comment: this is no longer working although it worked for me before. Now It only works when "contents" and "headings" present in the payload, I had to switch to Firebase Messaging for sending silent notification.